# Scala pattern matching in the for construct

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the following data model which I'm going to do pattern matching against later:

```
abstract class A
case class C(s:String) extends A

abstract class B extends A
case class D(i:Int) extends B
case class E(s:Int, e:Int) extends B
```

A is the abstract super type of the hierarchy. C is a concrete subclass of A. Other concrete subclasses of A are subclasses of B which is in turn a subclass of A.

Now if I write something like this, it works:

```
def match(a:A) a match {
   a:C => println("C")
   a:B => println("B")
}
```

However, in a for loop I cannot match against B. I assume that I need a constructor pattern, but since B is abstract, there is no constructor pattern for B.

```
val list:List[A] = List(C("a"), D(1), E(2,5), ...)

for (b:B <- list) println(b)  // Compile error
for (b@B <- list) println(b)  // Compile error
```

Here, I would like to print only B instances. Any workaround for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collect`:

```
list.collect { case b: B => println(b) }
```

If you want to better undertand this, I recommend to read about partial functions. [Here](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/12/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-4-pattern-matching-anonymous-functions.html) for example.

Comment: How do you use collect when nested iterations is needed? The prime reason I use for is that there is another type X which has a list of As. So I would like to write:

`class X(name:String, as:List[A])`

`listX = ... // a list of X`

`for(X <- listX; b:B <- X.as`) println(b)

Of course I can do it in two steps using a for and collect, but I was wondering if there is a one line solution for that...

Comment: @Ali: See my answer for another way to do it, using a for comprehension as you requested.

Answer (score 2):

Sergey is right; you'll have to give up `for` if you want to pattern match and filter only `B` instances. If you *still* want to use a `for` comprehension for whatever reason, I think one way is to just resort to using a guard:

```
for (b <- list if b.isInstanceOf[B]) println(b)
```

But it's always best to pick pattern-matching instead of `isInstanceOf`. So I'd go with the `collect` suggestion (if it made sense in the context of the rest of my code).

Another suggestion would be to define a **companion object** to `B` with the same name, and define the `unapply` method:

```
abstract class A
case class C(s:String) extends A

abstract class B extends A
object B { def unapply(b: B) = Option(b)  } // Added a companion to B
case class D(i:Int) extends B
case class E(s:Int, e:Int) extends B
```

Then you can do this:

```
for (B(b) <- list) println(b)
```

So that's not the 'constructor' of B, but the companion's `unapply` method.
It works, and that's what friends are for, right?

(See http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112 )

Answer (score 2):

If you ask me, the fact that you can't use pattern matching here is an unfortunate inconsistency of scala. Indeed scala **does** let you pattern match in for comprehensions, as this example will show:

```
val list:List[A] = List(C("a"), D(1), E(2,5)
for ((b:B,_) <- list.map(_ -> null)) println(b)
```

Here I temporarily wrap the elements into pairs (whith a dummy and unused second value) and then pattern match for a pair where the first element is of type B. As the output shows, you get the expected behaviour:

```
 D(1)
 E(2,5)
```

So there you go, scala **does** support filtering based on pattern matching (even when matching by type), it just seems that the grammar does not handle pattern matching a single element by type.

Obviously I am not advising to use this trick, this was just to illustrate. Using `collect` is certainly better.

Then again, there is another, more general solution if for some reason you really fancy for comprehensions more than anything:

```
object Value {
  def unapply[T]( value: T ) = Some( value )
}
for ( Value(b:B) <- list ) println(b)
```

We just introduced a dummy extractor in the `Value` object which just does nothing, so that `Value(b:B)` has the same meaning as just `b:B`, except that the former does compile. And unlike my earlier trick with pairs, it is relatively readable, and `Value` only has to be written once, you can use it at will then (in particular, no need for writing a new extractor for each type you want to pattern match against, as in @Faiz's answer. I'll let you find a better name than `Value` though.

Finally, there is another work around that works out of the box (credit goes to Daniel Sobral), but is slightly less readable and requires a dummy identifier (here `foo`):

```
for ( b @(foo:B) <- list ) println(b)
// or similarly:
for ( foo @(b:B) <- list ) println(b)
```

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you that not being able to pattern match using the type in 'for comprehensions' is inconsistent, but in the end I think I'll go with collect, at least I don't have to introduce other things.

Comment: I added another work around, suggested by Daniel Sobral in another question

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents: You can add a condition in the for comprehension checking type but that would **NOT** be as elegant as using `collect` which would take only instances of class B.